# Loop over images in web font file

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, webfonts

I have created a web font file using a set of svg icons. Also generated the associated CSS file using this https://icomoon.io/ app.

Now I can add individual images to the webpage using css classname like in Fontawesome. But what is the proper way to loop over all these images and show it all using javascript? Do we need to create a json array of all classnames and then loop over?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can select your DOM elements (divs, img and so on) and loop using JavaScript.
You can simply associate a class name on every DOM element (it will be use as a filter) and select each DOM element in a loop (a quick example below).

Alternatively you can have a JSON, defining your DOM elements there. Once again you need to loop in the JSON array, select the DOM element and applying your action on every element.
In my opinion this latest approach with JSON is to much for your use-case, and a simple loop on the result of document.querySelectorAll() will make job done.

http://jsfiddle.net/ppgrayry/2/

```
<div class="icon">icon</div>
<div class="icon">icon</div>
<div class="icon">icon</div>
<div class="icon">icon</div>
<div class="icon">icon</div>
<div class="icon">icon</div>


var elms = document.querySelectorAll('.icon');
for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    elms[i].classList.add('icon-active');
}


.icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;   
}
.icon-active {
        background-color: red !important;
}
```